# Balloon pop up over control mouse enter/exit

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

Hello,

Above is the program I am writing.  On the right panel is basically two custom controls (the blue rectangle area) I created and just added them as controls to the background panel control when this winform program loads.

I used MS paint to draw out the pop up balloon that I want to see when my mouse enter this control's area.  I want to do the following:

```
   1.  If mouse enter the control area, the yellow area balloon pop up and populate with the information of that specific control
   2.  If mouse move out of the control area, the pop up balloon disappear.
```

Can this be done with Winform application? I looked around and found out about `Tooltip` class but so far from researching I don't know if it does what I want to do.

I could be wrong but googling around gave me the impress that Tooltip offers very little in term of style.  Ideally I want to make this pop up balloon into almost like a border-less pop up window where I can put image , font ect.....at will.  Also Tooltip works if you hover over a button or specific field whereas I want the entire control area.

Can this be done? I appreciate if you can point me to any work around if there is one.

Comment: It *can* be done... but not without some significant work, I believe. I recently wrote up a non-modal `Notification` class for work that pretty much does this, but it took some effort. It would basically come down to defining a new "Form" and playing a bit with the properties to get it to display a dropshadow, not draw focus, etc.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.draw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a comment, but I figure I'll expand it into a full answer. This is assuming you want a new control, which isn't a tooltip, for maximum customizability. I did something similar to this for work recently, to act as a non-modal info popup that disappears when clicked.

### Creating a Custom Popup Form

What you want is essentially a floating popup that appears over your form, which means you'll want to define a new `Form` object, rather than a `UserControl`, as it won't actually be embedded within your other form.

Give it a multiline, non-editable textbox that you can fill with the information you want to populate, then simply call a new instance of the form on your `Mouse_Enter` event. Close it upon `Mouse_Leave`.

### Adjusting The Style

You'll have to play with it a bit to get it to actually act like a popup and not just a window. I'd recommend setting it to a non-modal popup, and removing the border. You can write a function to automatically size it to its contents. I don't imagine you'll want the user manually resizing it.

Some other things to look into would be overriding the `CreateParams` property that comes with the basic Form object. You can force `DropShadows` and `TopMost` forms without making the form modal. Overriding `ShowWithoutActivation` to always return true will prevent the form from stealing focus when it pops up.

I'm not sure if you can pull off rounded edges like you have in your mockup. Perhaps you can pull it off with some wizardry in the OnPaint() function, but I couldn't tell you how to do it.

---

It might be a bit of a pain for fiddling around with, but you can get some good functionality and appearance out of it. If you think you can pull it off acceptably with the ToolTip class, go for it. It took me about a week to get my notifications where I wanted them (though I added several features that you probably don't need to worry about).

#### Examples

Some keywords to look up in related searches would be `Toast Notification` and `Non-Modal Popup`. This might be some use:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442983/Android-Style-Toast-Notification-for-NET

Comment: Thanks Brad and KChaloux, i think your suggestions slowly point me in the proper direction.  However, I just had to make my life more difficult.. that is I want this floating  pop up to follow the mouse anywhere within the control area.  I guess I have to do the event to track mouse move event, then if it is still within the area then redraw the floating window location ..... hmm gonna be fun, I'll try it out first and update with any result I will come up.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have implemented custom user controls you might want to try it again. Make a control that is that style and color, changes it's size based on it's text. You can feed it information (such as the text to display) from your existing user control object. You can also have the mouse enter/leave code reside in your first user control.

If you're not sure how to make a rectangle with round corners you can either make it on the fly using a graphics object (which will turn into a bitmap on the screen) or make it how you want it to look in GIMP (or photoshop if you have it) then use that image as the background on your user control. Make the default background transparent (so your voids above the round corners are not grey). If you make a pre loaded image you'll need to be aware you will only be able to scale it equally in Y and X directions. unequal scaling will make it look distorted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the Mouse_Enter event on the  control?

Comment: I know about those events, I'm not worry about them.  My main sticky point is I don't know how to build up a control like the above balloon to hook up the Mouse_Enter and Mouse_Exit event to.